# Categories and articles in nested set model

Tags: mysql, nested

I'm designing a database that will employ the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). I have categories, and those categories have articles (i.e. each article belongs to a category).

My question is, should I put both categories and articles together in one table? Or should I put the categories in the nested set table, and the articles in a simple flat (non-hierarchical) table that joins to the `categories` table via a foreign key?

Comment: I would put together.

Comment: This is what I'm thinking as well, so it'd be easy to render the whole tree. Otherwise I'll have to do joins each time I want to view a category's articles.

Comment: In both situations you will need to do.

Comment: If both are in one nested set table, I can render the tree with one query, no joins.